# how do i make the inside profile of the basin as shown in the picture

Tags: modeling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpEZ.jpg

i have the 2d picture of the model answered by an amazing guy, however im still a bit clueless about how to approach it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Begin by creating a 18 vertex circle, keep only 1/4, mirror it, move it, subdivide:

[image]

Apply the *Mirror* modifier, create a smaller 24 vertex circle below the first one:

[image]

Then select the 2 circles and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to loopcut:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel:

[image]

Rearrange a bit with a new loopcut and some scales, you get your inner shape:

[image]

Select the top edge, extrude outwards, extrude down and so on:

[image]